# Android material drawer library issue

Tags: android

Here is my code, the part where it says 'DrawerView drawer'is my issue as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ws49.jpg)
The part above let me import the support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout but here there's nothing that i can import.

I'm still moderately new to android dev, so sorry if i'm doing anything wrong here

```
package com.nath.thecompletembguide;

import com.kskkbys.rate.RateThisApp;
import com.startapp.android.publish.SDKAdPreferences;
import com.startapp.android.publish.SDKAdPreferences.Gender;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppSDK;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Monitor launch times and interval from installation
        RateThisApp.onStart(this);
        // If the criteria is satisfied, "Rate this app" dialog will be shown
        RateThisApp.showRateDialogIfNeeded(this);
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppSDK.init(this, "105864370", "207677226", new SDKAdPreferences().setAge(10).setGender(Gender.MALE), false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        DrawerView drawer = (DrawerView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        }





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    if(android.R.id.home == item.getItemId()){
        finish();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.action_upgrade:
            Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nath.thecompletembguidepro"));
            startActivity(launchNewIntent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_about:
            Intent launchNewIntent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(launchNewIntent3);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_credits:
            Intent launchNewIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(launchNewIntent1, 0);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_changelogs:
            Intent launchNewIntent2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://nathcraft.com"));
            startActivity(launchNewIntent2);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Requires Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }}}
```

Comment: How do you add the dependency?

Comment: @Heinrich I just downloaded the zip, unzipped it then imported it into eclipse. Then added it to my Projects libraries in Properties>Android

Comment: As Android studio is now officially released you should probably switch to it. Eclipse won't be supported soon.

Answer (score 1):

Many libraries (prpbably due to android studio...) use the `java` folder as their `src` folder... Moving all code in the library in eclipse from the 'java' folder to the `src` folder, cleaning and rebuilding the library afterwards, and then refresh your own project, should solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Your imports look fine as far as I can see.  DrawerView isn't a thing. :)

Unfortunately, there's a lot of boilerplate code needed to get the navigation drawer up and working.  But, fortunately, there are lots of examples.

A good reference is the Google IO app, which was written by Roman Nurik and team, who have also made all the source code available.

Of interest to you will be the layout XML resources and the source code:

Layout XML (scroll down to "navdrawer")
https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/dfaf8b83ad1b3e7c8d1af0b08d59caf4223e0b95/android/src/main/res/layout

Source code:
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/dfaf8b83ad1b3e7c8d1af0b08d59caf4223e0b95/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java

To download the Application:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.iosched

Comment: DrawerView is a custom view he imported from my library.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using it in Eclipse too : i have made a copy of all Heinrich's packages and their layout, values... in my own project and it seems to work fine so far. Well i have a problem i'm not the only to have: the profile doesn't show, only the items